# Deleting duplicate rows on MySQL, getting a max row error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am deleting duplicate rows on MySQL and only leaving behind the old row (least id) but I am getting a max row error

[image]

```
DELETE n1
FROM item_audit n1, item_audit n2
WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.description = n2.description
```

Comment: What is your question? The error message even tells you how to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, with that join condition you are joining each row to **every** row before it (with the same description). This is one of those cases where a subquery will be much more effective than a join.

```
DELETE a
FROM item_audit a 
WHERE (a.id, a.description) NOT IN 
(SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT MIN(id), description 
   FROM item_audit 
   GROUP BY description
) AS realSubQ
)
```

Actually, assuming id is unique, it can even be simplier:

```
DELETE a
FROM item_audit a 
WHERE a.id NOT IN    
(SELECT * FROM
(   SELECT MIN(id)
   FROM item_audit 
   GROUP BY description
) AS realSubQ
)
```

As you discovered, MySQL needs to be "tricked" into being able to use the delete target in a subquery with the extra `select *` wrapper.

---

Alternatively, a join on the subquery could be used to reduce the size of the intermediate result set created behind the scenes.

```
DELETE a 
FROM item_audit a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) AS firstId FROM item_audit GROUP BY description) AS aFirst
ON a.id = aFirst.firstId
WHERE aFirst.firstId IS NULL
;
```

If that fails, you can insert the first id's into a temp table, and should be able to do subquery version with that.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `old_ids`
SELECT MIN(ID) AS id 
FROM item_audit 
GROUP BY description;

DELETE a 
FROM item_audit a 
LEFT JOIN old_ids ON a.id = old_ids.id 
WHERE old_ids.id IS NULL
;
```

In any of these cases, a LIMIT clause can be placed very last to accomplish an incremental delete. The last, temp table, version has the benefit that the subquery will not need re-evaluated after every incremental delete (and the temporary table can be indexed to speed things up as well).

Comment: where do you compare the **description** . you will remove all rows. only 1 will left

Comment: error near FROM item_audit a 
WHERE (a.id, a.description) NOT IN (
   SELECT MIN(id), description

Comment: @BerndBuffen if you're talking about the latter example, description does not need compared; the subquery groups on description, so it's results consists of the "oldest" id for each description.

Comment: @user7498826 fixed it, forgot I had to account for the table alias.

Comment: #1093 - Table 'a' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: @user7498826 Ah, yeah, forgot MySQL isn't always happy with subqueries on the same table in DELETEs; added an alternate join, and temp table suggestion.

Comment: so i am using DELETE FROM item_audit
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MIN(n.id)
                            FROM item_audit n
                        GROUP BY n.description) x)

Comment: i know get a time out error how can i tweak that to maybe delete with a limit

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that nesting a subquery to trick mysql before... you should just be able to put a limit after your last parenthesis.